# Erro ao compilar função no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Ao tentar compilar a seguinte function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_id_fornecedor(Nomefornecedor in varchar(50)) 
RETURN integer  IS
codigoforncedor integer;
BEGIN   
SELECT codfornecedor INTO codigofornecedor FROM TBFORNECEDOR WHERE NOFORNECEDOR=Nomefornecedor;
IF codigofornecedor <> NULL THEN
RETURN codigofornecedor;
ELSE Raise_Application_Error(-20004,
                             'Fornecedor não existe: ' || nomefornecedor);

END IF;      
END;
```

obtenho o seguinte erro:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for
>   "(" to continue.
>
> Compile error at line 1, column 53 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
>
> Compile error at line 12, column 21

Answer (score 1):

Em funções do Oracle, não é necessário especifica o tamanho da coluna no parâmetro de entrada, dessa forma, a declaração da sua função ficaria assim:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_id_fornecedor(nomefornecedor IN VARCHAR)
...
```